# Confidence intervals: how do we have to interpret them?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval

I have a very basic question regarding confidence intervals. I am confused between two interpretations of confidence intervals.

Interpretation 1:

If repeated samples were taken and the 95% confidence interval computed for each sample, 95% of the intervals would contain the population mean.5% of the intervals would not contain the population mean

Interpretation 2:
If we were to take 100 additional samples, 95 times out of 100, the population mean rate would fall between 2.5% and 17.5%.

Which of these would be correct?

Comment: Maybe the section 3. of this answer will help you: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167972/why-is-there-a-need-for-a-sampling-distribution-to-find-confidence-intervals/167998#167998

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. From that it seems to me that the first implication is correct

Comment: I agree with you, don't thank me, but vote for my answer I referred to if you think it helped you

Comment: Also see discussion [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11609/clarification-on-interpreting-confidence-intervals) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138528/does-a-confidence-interval-actually-provide-a-measure-of-the-uncertainty-of-a-pa/138546#138546) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104499/what-is-the-most-likely-meaning-of-a-confidence-interval/104564#104564)